# How to Perform Vectorised Binning Using Only Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, vectorization, slice

I am trying to find the correct syntax to select a slice of rows in a Pandas DataFrame, conditional on a multi-dimensional slice.

I want to perform a histogram binning, by providing bins in a multidimensional numpy array, and comparing vectorially whether a record fits in one bin or another. The result should be a 1 dimensional numpy array, with the number of items in each bin.

My initial model attempt is below, for reference, although I have since provided a partial implementation (using a loop instead) in an answer below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## Generate Random Data
X = np.random.normal(0.5,0.1,100)

## Populate a Pandas DataFrame
DF = pd.DataFrame({'x':X})

## Some example, hardcoded 1D bins. 
bins = np.array([
                [[0.0,0.2]],
                [[0.2,0.4]],
                [[0.4,0.6]],
                [[0.6,0.8]],
                [[0.8,1.0]]
                ])

hist = np.zeros(shape=(4,))
hist[:] = np.sum(
                 DF.loc[   (DF >= bins[:,:,0]) &
                           (DF > bins[:,:,1])
                        ].dropna(how='all')
                 )
```

In general, the data are n-dimensional, and the bins follow the above pattern, with:

```
[[x_min, x_max], [y_min, ymax], [z_min, z_max]]
```

for each bin (hence the apparent 'extra' layer of nesting in the 1D example above). Therefore the slicing should work for DataFrames of multiple columns, such that

```
DF['x'] >= x_min and DF['x'] < x_max and 
DF['y'] >= y_min and DF['y'] < y_max
```

etc. and hence needs to be dimension-agnostic; the slicing approach appears to be the most natural way of achieving this, and should be computationally more efficient if achievable.

If not, the list-comprehension approach in my answer could be tried - but I have had troubles with multidimensionality.

Comment: Your code does not run, probably because `bins[:][0]` and `bins[:][1]` are still arrays. However, please ensure running code or or add code with errors only with directly explaining there what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks; I'm aware the code doesn't run - that's kind of the problem! I can't see how to write that line (beginning `hist[:] = `) such that I will populate the hist object correctly. I would be grateful for suggestions on how to write this slice correctly, or if it is not possible, an explanation of why or how to do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you really need pandas, but numpy has a multidimensional histogram function called `histogramdd`.

Here is a test loop which generates three arrays with increasing number of columns, all 100 rows long and corresponding bin arrays, all with your sample borders from above.

Just have a look if this is what you were looking for:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    data = np.random.random([100, i])
    bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 6)
    bins = [bins for _ in range(i)]
    print('shape of data: ', np.shape(data))
    print('bin borders: ',bins)
    print('\nresult: ', np.histogramdd(data, bins), '\n\n')
```

result:

```
shape of data:  (100, 1)
bin borders:  [array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])]

result:  (array([ 14.,  26.,  21.,  24.,  15.]), [array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])]) 


shape of data:  (100, 2)
bin borders:  [array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ]), array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])]

result:  (array([[  5.,   7.,   5.,   2.,   3.],
       [  5.,   4.,   5.,   3.,   1.],
       [  5.,   3.,   7.,   1.,   3.],
       [  2.,   6.,   4.,   3.,   7.],
       [  1.,  11.,   3.,   2.,   2.]]), [array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ]), array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])]) 


shape of data:  (100, 3)
bin borders:  [array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ]), array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ]), array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])]

result:  (array([[[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  0.,  2.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  1.]],

       [[ 2.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  4.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  2.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  3.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.]]]), [array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ]), array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ]), array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])])
```

Comment: Thanks - I am familiar with numpy's own histogram provisions and their limitations, and am in fact looking to 'replace' these with a more general formulation. I have now got a partial solution to the problem as stated, so I will post this as an answer; but it is not vectorised and seems sub-optimal, so I will wait for superior approaches - hopefully using my answer for more inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment to SpghttCd's answer, I have found a working approach which uses a list comprehension instead of a slice, when filling the histogram. It appears to accurately calculate the number of records in each bin (tested in 1D and 2D), but is inelegant and I would be grateful for improvements for people more intimately familiar with the pandas library. It appears possibly slightly dodgy due to integer rounding as well.

I present the code below, with the example above extended to 2D.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

## Generate Random Data
X = np.random.normal(0.5,0.1,150)
Y = np.random.normal(0.5,0.2,150)

## Populate a Pandas DataFrame
DF = pd.DataFrame({'x':X,'y':Y})

## Some example, hardcoded 2D bins. 
bins = np.array([
            [[0.0,0.2],[0.0,1.5]],
            [[0.2,0.4],[0.0,1.5]],
            [[0.4,0.6],[0.0,1.5]],
            [[0.6,0.8],[0.0,1.5]],
            [[0.8,1.0],[0.0,1.5]]
            ])


hist = np.array([  
                np.product(  
                          np.sum(     (DF.iloc[:,:] >= bins[:,:,0][i][:]) & 
                                      (DF.iloc[:,:] <  bins[:,:,1][i][:])
                          ))/len(DF) 
                 for i in range(len(bins)) ], dtype=np.int32)[:,0]


print(hist)    
print(sum(hist))

## 2D Plot
plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3.5))
plt.scatter(DF['x'],DF['y'], 5, 'k')
axes.set_xlabel('x')
axes.set_xlabel('y')
axes.set_xlim(-0.5,1.5)
axes.set_ylim(-0.5,2)

# Create a Rectangle patch for each bin and plot
for i,bin in enumerate(bins):

    rect = patches.Rectangle(   (bin[0][0],bin[1][0]),
                                bin[0][1]-bin[0][0],
                                bin[1][1]-bin[1][0],
                                linewidth=1,
                                edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
    # Add the patch to the Axes
    axes.add_patch(rect)

plt.show()
```

This is part of a personal project to re-invent N-dimensional histograms in Python, with reference to a discussion in this [SciComp question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/30023).